# How to grab the value from a droppable li jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of droppable li elements. When I drag and drop it on to a table I want to take the value of the li element and insert it in to the table value. But I don't know what code to use to detect the value of the li element.... here is my code.

```
$(function()
{
$( "#planningData" ).sortable(
    {
    revert: true
    });
 $(".hName").droppable(
    {
    drop: function (event, ui)
        {
        var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr.val();

        //Below is where I am trying to detect what the text value of the li is.
        var droppableId = $(this).siblings(".hInput").attr('id');
        $(this).html(draggableId);

        var hourData = draggableId;
        var hourNumber = droppableId;
        alert(hourData, hourNumber);
        $.post("UpdateTime.php",
        {
            loginName: "<?php echo $user; ?>",
            hourData: hourData,
            hourNumber: hourNumber
        },
    function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        });
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.hInput` is the `li` element?

```
$("#" + droppableId).text();
```